# How rewrite XML

Tags: python

I have file of XML. I need search in this file string and rewrite new string in the same place. For example:

Searched: `<Node name="hMKD11CY022_HW" type="T_REAL" access="ReadWrite" />\n`

Rewrite: `<Node name="hMKD11CY022_HW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />\n`

```
from __future__ import print_function
import fileinput
import os
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print("SCRIPT")

f = open('example.xml','r+')
line = f.readline()
while line:
    line = f.readline()
    if line.find('hMKD11CY022_HW') != -1 :
        print(line)
        f.write('<Node name="hMKD11CY022_HW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />\n');
        print("SPAMER")
f.close()
print()
```

my XML:

```
<Comment>XXXXXXXX</Comment>
        </Node>
        <Node name="hMKD11CY022_HW" type="T_REAL" access="ReadWrite" />
        <Node name="hMKD11CY022_QHW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
        <Node name="hMKD12CY021_HW" type="T_REAL" access="ReadWrite" />
        <Node name="hMKD12CY021_QHW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
        <Node name="hMKD12CY022_HW" type="T_REAL" access="ReadWrite" />
        <Node name="hMKD12CY022_QHW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
        <Node name="hMKY01DE010A_QHW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
        <Node name="hMKY01DE010D_QHW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
        <Node name="hMYB01GS001_QHW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
        <Node name="vMBP13AA051_XC02" type="T_BOOL" access="ReadWrite" />
        <Node name="vMBP13AA151_XC02" type="T_BOOL" access="ReadWrite" />
        <Node name="vMBP15AA151_XC02" type="T_BOOL" access="ReadWrite" />
        <Node name="vvMBA10CS101_XM26" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
        <Node name="vvMBA10CS101_XQ01" type="T_REAL" access="ReadWrite" />
        <Node name="vvMBA10CS102_XM26" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
        <Node name="vvMBA10CS102_XQ01" type="T_REAL" access="ReadWrite" />
        <Node name="vvMBA10CS103_XM26" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
        <Node name="vvMBA10CS103_XQ01" type="T_REAL" access="ReadWrite" />
        <Node name="vvMBA10CS902_XM26" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
        <Node name="vvMBA10CS902_XQ01" type="T_REAL" access="ReadWrite" />
      </Node>
```

Comment: POST a sample of your XML file.

Comment: see if the answer posted below helped? if it did, you may accept it by clicking on the tick sign beside it. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath):

```py
from lxml import etree

with open("so.xml") as f:
    # Parse the input.
    tree = etree.parse(f)

    # Find the node we are interested in.
    node = tree.xpath("/root/Node[@name=\"hMKD11CY022_HW\"]")[0]

    # Set the "type" attribute value.
    node.set("type", "T_BYTE")

    # Save the tree to a new file.
    with open("so.out.xml", "wb") as g:
        tree.write(g)
```

For the input file `so.xml`

```xml
<root>
<Node name="hMKD11CY022_HW" type="T_REAL" access="ReadWrite" />
</root>
```

this will write the output file `so.out.xml`:

```xml
<root>
<Node name="hMKD11CY022_HW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite"/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replaces all `T_REAL` with `T_BYTE`:

```
with open('file.xml', 'r+') as f:
    data = f.read().replace('T_REAL', 'T_BYTE')
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the line:

```
<Node name="hMKD11CY022_HW" type="T_REAL" access="ReadWrite" />
```

to this:

```
<Node name="hMKD11CY022_HW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
```

Using fileinput:

```
import fileinput

replaced_text = 'type="T_BYTE"'
for line in fileinput.input("list.txt", inplace=1):
    search = line.find("hMKD11CY022_HW")
    if search > 0:
       line = line.replace('type="T_REAL"',replaced_text)
       print(line)
    else:
        print(line.strip())
```

OUTPUT:

```
<Comment>XXXXXXXX</Comment>
</Node>
<Node name="hMKD11CY022_HW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="hMKD11CY022_QHW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="hMKD12CY021_HW" type="T_REAL" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="hMKD12CY021_QHW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="hMKD12CY022_HW" type="T_REAL" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="hMKD12CY022_QHW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="hMKY01DE010A_QHW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="hMKY01DE010D_QHW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="hMYB01GS001_QHW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vMBP13AA051_XC02" type="T_BOOL" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vMBP13AA151_XC02" type="T_BOOL" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vMBP15AA151_XC02" type="T_BOOL" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vvMBA10CS101_XM26" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vvMBA10CS101_XQ01" type="T_REAL" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vvMBA10CS102_XM26" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vvMBA10CS102_XQ01" type="T_REAL" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vvMBA10CS103_XM26" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vvMBA10CS103_XQ01" type="T_REAL" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vvMBA10CS902_XM26" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vvMBA10CS902_XQ01" type="T_REAL" access="ReadWrite" />
</Node>
```

**EDIT:**

To replace all the `type="T_REAL"` to `type="T_BYTE"`:

```
import fileinput

to_replace = 'T_REAL'
replace_with = 'T_BYTE'

for line in fileinput.input("list.txt", inplace=1):
    line = line.replace(to_replace,replace_with)
    print(line.strip())
```

OUTPUT:

```
<Comment>XXXXXXXX</Comment>
</Node>
<Node name="hMKD11CY022_HW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="hMKD11CY022_QHW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="hMKD12CY021_HW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="hMKD12CY021_QHW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="hMKD12CY022_HW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="hMKD12CY022_QHW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="hMKY01DE010A_QHW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="hMKY01DE010D_QHW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="hMYB01GS001_QHW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vMBP13AA051_XC02" type="T_BOOL" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vMBP13AA151_XC02" type="T_BOOL" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vMBP15AA151_XC02" type="T_BOOL" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vvMBA10CS101_XM26" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vvMBA10CS101_XQ01" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vvMBA10CS102_XM26" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vvMBA10CS102_XQ01" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vvMBA10CS103_XM26" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vvMBA10CS103_XQ01" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vvMBA10CS902_XM26" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vvMBA10CS902_XQ01" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
</Node>
```

**EDIT 2:**

To replace all the `type="T_REAL"` and `type="T_BOOL"` to `type="T_BYTE"`:

```
import fileinput

to_replace = 'T_REAL'
to_replace_bool = 'T_BOOL'
replace_with = 'T_BYTE'

for line in fileinput.input("list.txt", inplace=1):
    t_real = line.find('T_REAL')
    t_bool = line.find('T_BOOL')

    if t_real > 0:
        line = line.replace(to_replace,replace_with)
        print(line.strip())
    elif t_bool > 0:
        line = line.replace(to_replace_bool, replace_with)
        print(line.strip())
    else:
        print(line.strip())
```

OUTPUT:

```
<Comment>XXXXXXXX</Comment>
</Node>
<Node name="hMKD11CY022_HW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="hMKD11CY022_QHW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="hMKD12CY021_HW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="hMKD12CY021_QHW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="hMKD12CY022_HW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="hMKD12CY022_QHW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="hMKY01DE010A_QHW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="hMKY01DE010D_QHW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="hMYB01GS001_QHW" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vMBP13AA051_XC02" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vMBP13AA151_XC02" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vMBP15AA151_XC02" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vvMBA10CS101_XM26" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vvMBA10CS101_XQ01" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vvMBA10CS102_XM26" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vvMBA10CS102_XQ01" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vvMBA10CS103_XM26" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vvMBA10CS103_XQ01" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vvMBA10CS902_XM26" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
<Node name="vvMBA10CS902_XQ01" type="T_BYTE" access="ReadWrite" />
</Node>
```